# How to create angle like this in CSS

Tags: css

...

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/329122/1104381445-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/329122/1104381445-My-Desktop.png)

I checked here http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/ but all corners are in rounded shape.

Comment: The image seems to be broken. Please fix it or at least add a good description.

Answer (score 3):

[Jquery Corner Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

> Corner is a simple plugin for creating rounded (or other styled)
>   corners on elements.

Comment: so it's not possible using css3only

Comment: @metal-gear-solid sorry man i really didn't checkout the tags... I thought you were searching for a jquery plugin..

Comment: it's not possible in in css3 so i will go for this jquery plugin

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur -  I'm using this code `$("#item3 li:last").corner("br bevel");`

Comment: @metal it looks fine to me... Post a picture of this as what you get?

Comment: @metal i found a way... Your back ground color seems to be in red right!..... If so go to corner.js and find `#ffffff` and replace it with your red color code...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, only round/elliptical borders are available through CSS. If you want other shapes you will have to use an image.

It's possible to get straight diagonals by abusing border joins:

```
<div style="background: gray; height: 100px; width: 200px; position: relative;">
    <div style="height: 1px; width: 1px; border-top: solid gray 20px; border-right: solid white 20px; position: absolute; bottom: -1px; right: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

Not sure that's an especially good idea though.

Comment: This idea is good I have to make this for `<li><a href="#> some text </a> </li>`. Is it possible to apply css only to <li> or <a>. using this type of technique http://www.russellheimlich.com/blog/pure-css-shapes-triangles-delicious-logo-and-hearts/. Actually i have to make dropdown like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767150/how-to-make-this-type-transparent-dropdown-with-flat-angle-keeping-markup-semanti

Answer (score 1):

Improving on bobince's idea, which uses two elements, have you tried using backgrounds? They allow you to stick a normal coloured background plus the moving custom background stuck to the bottom:

```
element {
  background: gray url(cornerImage) no-repeat bottom right;
}
```

This is superior to a jQuery plugin as no scripting is needed (which should be avoided for presentation as much as possible). The corner image will just be a small square image that has grey and white triangles.