# How to give transparent hexagon angle at the last <li> only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, css

I have to make menu like this.
[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/330421/1104422739-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/330421/1104422739-My-Desktop.png)

- Items of drop-down can be increased
  and decreased If client will add or remove pages.
- width of drop-down's will depend on how many character in page title
  name.
- angle only needed at last item's right bottom corner.

I Know how to make drop-down menu and how to give cross browser transparency , but I want to know How to give needed angle to **right bottom angle** while keeping transparency.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [jQuery corner demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/):

```
$("#item3 li:last").corner("br bevel");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the opacity of the elements with CSS, this will work with all major browsers:

```
.transparent_class {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

you need to do this using lists, you can apply a special class to the last li to make it look different. this jquery line might help you

```
$("#item3 li:last").addClass("special_corner");
```

**UPDATE**:

why dont you take alook at [JQuery Corner Demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

Comment: Thanks for reply I'm asking for whole concept . especially for bottom corner.

Comment: @But what i will put for special corner? drod down's items width and height both are not fixed. item can be increased or decreased on other submenu and width if dropdown depends on largest text inside dropdown

Comment: @metal-gear-solid

see this for creating what you want http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: @tim - i need corner at one side only and keeping markup semantic

Comment: Ok, so your code should look like this:

$(this).corner("br bevel");

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Son of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) drop down menus.  The special styling you want would require a class to be assigned to the last `<li>` in any `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML 5

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
    <li>Item 3.1</li>
    <li>Item 3.2</li>
    <li>Item 3.3</li>
    <li>Item 3.4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>etc......
</ul>
</nav>
```

css

border-bottom-right-image: